# Calculate Income Of the Month [Puzzle]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Mr. Jill requires Rs 6000 per month to maintain his family. He saves 20% of any amount that he earns above Rs. 6000 but below Rs 7000 in a month. He saves 30% of amount that he earns above Rs 7000 but below Rs 8000 in a month. If Mr. Jill spends Rs 6975 on a month, what is his income for that month ?

Comment: Suppose he makes $7000+x$. Can you compute how much he spends?

Comment: will it be not 0.7x ?

Comment: No. That's just how much he spends of the part between 7000 and 8000, but he's also spending some of the part between 6000 and 7000, and presumably spending all of the amount below 6000.

Comment: ah I got it .. he spend 7000 + x - 0.3x - 200 .. damn .. its now solved

Comment: Good --- write it up, and post it as an answer, and then (when the software lets you) you can accept your answer, and help to clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the total amount spent in a month (6975), you could convert the saving percentages (20%, 30%) into spending percentages (80%, 70%).

So the total money spent are:

```
6000,                                   if income<6000
6000+0.8(income-6000)                   if income<7000
6000+0.8*1000+0.7(income-7000)          else
```

You have to check the money spent when income is 7000. This gives you 6800. Since he spent more than that, he earned more than 7000. So it's the third option ($income\ge7000$)

6000+800+0.7(income-7000)=6950

$0.7(income-7000)=150$

$income-7000=\frac{150}{0.7}$

$income=7000+\frac{150}{0.7}$